# How to change log level of envoy proxy with environment variable

Tags: envoyproxy

How can I change the default log level of the envoy proxy from info to something else ( like debug ) with an Environment variable? I know there is an `--log-level` [option](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/cli#cmdoption-l) when running envoy, but I don't want to change the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` of the docker file in order to add this option, so I want to change it with an ENV.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add an environment variable in your docker file

   `ENV ENVOY_LOG_LEVEL=debug`
2. Then, in your ENTRYPOINT or cmd, use the variable to set the log level

   `envoy -c <path_to_config> --log-level ${ENVOY_LOG_LEVEL}`
3. Build and run your docker image. log level will now be set to debug.

You can change the log level dynamically too by using the envoy admin endpoints. First, make sure the admin endpoint is enabled in your envoy configuration:

admin:

```
access_log_path: <path_to_access_log>
address:
socket_address:
address: 0.0.0.0
port_value: 9901
```

4. Use a http client (curl) to send a post request to the /logging endpoint with log level as the payload

   `curl -XPOST http://localhost:9901/logging?level=debug`

this will change log level to debug now you can replace "debug" with other levels

5. Check envoy logs to see the updated log level.

you now can change  default log level of envoy proxy without modifying the docker file.

Comment: Thanks. I will give you the bounty but won't accept it cause it's not the direct answer for the question. The first approach still has to change the dockerfile or args and I don't want to do this.

Comment: @meshkati, ahan i will check into it again and modify the answer

Answer (score 1):

As for

[envoyproxy/envoy:v1.28.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/envoyproxy/envoy/v1.28.0/images/sha256-1a7335610e70a7579f2fee9b8c0f3bb2c7f22b72e52381ff749e5b9df3692883?context=explore),
environmental variable to change log level was `loglevel` , not ENVOY_LOG_LEVEL.

This fact is not officially shown, so this might be changed in the future version.

You can specify `info`, `debug`, `trace`,... as you would in CLI option.

> -l ,  --log-level 
> Log levels: [trace][debug][info][warning
> |warn][error][critical][off]